# What is the best way to get the values of a radio button set with lxml?

Tags: python, lxml

For example I have the following radio buttons:

```
<input type="radio" name="hand"  id='hand_left' checked value="L"> 
  <label for='hand_left'>Left</label>

<input type="radio" name="hand" id='hand_right' value="R"> 
  <label for='hand_right'>Right</label>
```

And have the following parsing code:

```
import lxml.html as lh

doc=lh.parse(response) # response is the response of 
                       # http post that returns the above html

for el in doc.iter('input'):
   if el.name == 'hand':
     print el
```

That prints out two InputElements, but lxml only returns a value for the checked one and returns None for the unchecked one (as per the lxml docs). I'd like to get each of the potential values regardless of which one is checked.

```
<InputElement 8715f8c name='hand' type='radio'>
<InputElement 8715f8f name='hand' type='radio'>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `el.attrib['value']` instead of `el.value`